# Validation Profiles still execute if previous profiles throw error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom sign-up policy that has 3 validation profiles.

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="UsernameCheck" ContinueOnError = "false"/>
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="API-VerifyStep1"  ContinueOnError = "false"/>
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" ContinueOnError="false" />

<TechnicalProfile Id="UsernameCheck">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- Required claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdNotFound" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertObjectIdObjectIdNotFoundAreEqual" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>


<TechnicalProfile Id="API-VerifyStep1">
<DisplayName>Validate user's input data and return if valid to sign-up</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://...</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_accessNumber"  />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />

</InputClaims>

<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_error" PartnerClaimType="extension_error" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_message"  PartnerClaimType="extension_message" DefaultValue="Error"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" /> 

</OutputClaims>
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
   <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertErrorMessageFalseStep1" />
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
```

The problem is all validation profiles are executed regarldess of throwing an error. If either of the first two throw an error I receive a message on the sign-up page. However, the user still gets added to Azure AD. Why does it do this? What is the point of ContinueOnError? How do I ensure the write only happens after the other two are done validating?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContinueOnError is by default false, so you shouldn't need to specify it as long as you want the default behavior.

Since you are using a restful provider, I suspect you are running into the issue mentioned by following thread - 
[Custom policy REST API ValidationTechnicalProfile ContinueOnError not working for HTTP codes like 404 NotFound and 401 unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722773/custom-policy-rest-api-validationtechnicalprofile-continueonerror-not-working-fo)

Basically the validation technical profile needs to return 409. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile

You can also use Preconditions as mentioned on the above page to avoid executing a technical profile.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I followed a tutorial that has a REST API return a claim with an error in it. I will try using preconditions before having it throw 409 errors. Thanks again!